# Get value by clicking on buttons which are generated from while loop in php

Tags: php

I have a table in which the data is generated from while loop in php. In every row there is a cell which holds the id of row and a button which is about to get the id of each row selected.How can i get the id by clicking the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in several ways.

But the main point is that you need to put `id` data on each row by PHP code.

You mentioned that you put a unique ID in HTML `id` property on the `tr` element. But this would not be a convenient way.

In this case, you need to define row's click event in PHP code like the following.

```
echo '<tr id="row<?php echo $id ?>" onclick="myClickFunc(<?php echo $id ?>)">xxxx</tr>';
```

And your JS code would be:

```
function myClickFunc(id) {
   console.log('ROW ID:', id);
}
```

Or you can define a data attribute for `id` and `class` on rows and I recommend using `jQuery` for DOM manipulation.

```
echo '<tr id="row<?php echo $id ?>" class="table-row" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>">xxxx</tr>';
```

And you can get id like the following with the `jQuery` library.

```
$(".table-row").click(function()) {
   var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
   console.log('ROW ID:', id);
});
```